# Should an IVI with Android Automotive OS be CTS tested and certified by Google before mass production?

Tags: android, cts, automotive

I'm working in a company building Android-based IVI system for Tier1/OEM/aftermarket. Before the release of Android Automotive OS, we ported Android for Phone on IVI hardware and do customizations to bring in vehicle-related features like rear view camera, HVAC control, BT music, navigation, steering wheel control, etc. At that time, our products didn't need to be certified by Google and we could choose whether to test CTS or not. But with Android Automotive OS, I'm not sure if the CTS test should be carried out and the report must be sent to Google for certification, or even integrate GMS?

In the latest Android CDD document: https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf. I can see that there are some hardware and software requirements for Automotive devices. But I can't find any further information about what exactly should be conformed before shipping a vehicle with Android Automotive OS based IVI in different countries.

Looking forward to any tips & info. Thanks a lot!

BR

Answer (score 0):

It is still the same way you did for your last project.
I would say it up to you.
There is nothing diferences until now for what we called Android Automotive OS..
There is no "Android Automotive OS" actually .. it is simply Android PLUS some added service , Vehicle HAL, CarService 
So nothing special... Android still violate many Automotive requirement regrading safety and Performance. That why many OEM like GM have to customize alot of things on top Android
Basically if your IVI contain Android Auto certification then you need to do CTS and other stuff to make Google say YES if not... then Who care...